# Ruby: how convert string to hash with keywords list

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to convert this string
s= "Sub-attr:IVerb-attr:was born Object-attr:on theDate-attr:2022-01-01"

to Hash :

{
Sub-attr: "I",
Verb-attr: "was born",
Object-attr: "on the",
Date-attr: "2022-01-01"
}

To do that, I think to split the string first. Then convert the array to Hash by pair elements.

But I cannot split correctly by using the expression as following

```
s.scan(/(Sub-attr|Verb-attr|Object-attr|Date-attr):(.*)/)
```

Outputs:
[["Sub-attr", "IVerb-attr:was bornObject-attr:on theDate-attr:2022-01-01"]]

Has anybody an idea please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```rb
s= "Sub-attr:IVerb-attr:was born Object-attr:on theDate-attr:2022-01-01"
puts s.scan(/([\w-]+):(.*?)(?=(?:Sub-attr|Verb-attr|Object-attr|Date-attr):|\z)/).to_h
# => {"Sub-attr"=>"I", "Verb-attr"=>"was born ", "Object-attr"=>"on the", "Date-attr"=>"2022-01-01"}
```

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/8eEJgy) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVdxrV/1).

*Details*:

- `([\w-]+)`  - Group 1: one or more word or hyphen chars
- `:` - a colon
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible...
- `(?=(?:Sub-attr|Verb-attr|Object-attr|Date-attr):|\z)` - up to either `Sub-attr:`, `Verb-attr:`, `Object-attr:` or `Date-attr:` string or end of string.

Comment: It's working well. Thank you also for your explanations!